# How big can you go with Cloud Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Just curious, since I can't find an answer anywhere (I've checked the documentation, and done reasonable due diligence with Googling third party sources).

Is there a limit to the number of nodes you can have with Cloud Spanner?
(I experimented with trying to deploy a thousand node cluster, and the console UI didn't object, the only thing that was stopping me was the hourly price tag!)

I assume at some point you enter diminishing returns ...

TIA

Comment: Spanner is advertised to be capable to scale horizontally to _thousands_ of nodes. Although there must be a maximum theoretical limit, I'm pretty sure that the limit is far beyond any reasonable practical need or wallet :)

Answer (score 2):

By default the maximum nodes per project is 15, limited by Quota which can be rised by asking for a [Quota Increase](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSczQOE6S_1MUTf4KBpF_i-cJVMQloUEZQ71KcNQzbAkWDDuVw/viewform?c=0&w=1)

Each node can be up to 2 TB of information so the default maximun size is 30 TB

As of the limit when asking for the quota increase I've seen up to thousands, basically the limit is on the billing amount for you.

Comment: Spanner has doubled the storage capacity for all instances from 2TB storage per node to 4TB storage per node to help reduce the compute cost of storage intensive workloads .  https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/spanner-has-doubled-the-storage-per-node-to-4tb-from-2tb